# In C# what is the equivalent of "is" keyword but using Type objects

Tags: c#, introspection

An easy question I guess, but in the documentation of the Type class they only talk of interfaces on the GetInterfaces method.

i.e. typeof(ChildClass).XXX(typeof(ParentClass)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on what you need; IsAssignableFrom, perhaps:

```
bool stringIsObj = typeof(object).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string));
```

or `IsSubclassOf`:

```
bool stringIsObj = typeof(string).IsSubclassOf(typeof(object));
```

Comment: do you know what the diference is?

Comment: Sure; interfaces will work differently (they won't be subclasses) - and Foo will be assignable from Foo, but Foo isn't a subclass of Foo (IsSubclassOf is a **strict** subclass)

Comment: For example, this is true: bool stringIsComparable = typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string));

Comment: Marc - Out of curiosity, how do you monitor for new questions that you answer? :)

Comment: Marc - Also, how do you monitor comments to your answer?

Comment: Answer to both... I simply pop in occasionally; sometimes there is something to do; sometimes there isn't...

Answer (score 2):

typeof(ParentClass).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ChildClass))

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you search for an equivalent. Instead of using the "is" keyword like this:

```
if (object is class)
{ ... }
```

you could simply compare the types of those two like this:

```
if( typeof(object) == typeof(class)
{ ... }
```

BUT: this is not the same, the "is" keyword can determine if the object-class is of the specified class, an inheritence of that class, implements the interface, etc, whereas the typeof() equivalence just compares the actual type.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185559/in-c-what-is-the-equivalent-of-is-keyword-but-using-type-objects/1185570#1185570.